# Laravel Collection in Json resource

Tags: php, laravel

I have some problems with Laravel resources.
I have json object and it have some relations in it, and it looks like this.

```
{
    "product": {
        "id": "087fd1dd-d4e2-4a1a-8f62-0481203e5afd",
        "sku": "2014",
        "slug": "container200",
        "type": "accessory",
        "deleted_at": null,
        "created_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:27.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:27.000000Z",
        "category": [],
        "info": [
            {
                "id": "0cb10e21-1772-49fc-bff3-90f30cf899c3",
                "product_id": "087fd1dd-d4e2-4a1a-8f62-0481203e5afd",
                "country_id": "375759b3-7aaa-4826-a767-7c071ebe87c0",
                "name": "Finer Dicer Container 200ml",
                "description": "#",
                "created_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:28.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:28.000000Z",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "country": {
                    "id": "375759b3-7aaa-4826-a767-7c071ebe87c0",
                    "name": "Italy",
                    "iso_alpha_2": "IT",
                    "iso_alpha_3": "ITA",
                    "native_name": "Italien",
                    "phone_code": 39,
                    "capital": "Rome",
                    "continent": "Europe",
                    "languages": "{\"bar\":\"Austro-Bavarian German\",\"ita\":\"Italian\",\"srd\":\"Sardinian\"}",
                    "address_format": "{{recipient}}\n{{street}}\n{{postalcode}} {{city}} {{region_short}}\n{{country}}",
                    "flag": "https://cdn.countryflags.com/thumbs/italy/flag-400.png",
                    "time_zone": "[\"Europe\\/Rome\"]",
                    "locales": null,
                    "isActive": null,
                    "currency_id": "00cb7204-fb53-4cb7-8f59-ea3fe824c803",
                    "created_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:26.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:26.000000Z",
                    "deleted_at": null
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "0d5794fc-0934-4bef-bddc-c3d42ac59d12",
                "product_id": "087fd1dd-d4e2-4a1a-8f62-0481203e5afd",
                "country_id": "98e13d4f-2ba3-49f5-a884-800f8158b4c8",
                "name": "Finer Dicer Container 200ml",
                "description": "#",
                "created_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:28.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:28.000000Z",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "country": {
                    "id": "98e13d4f-2ba3-49f5-a884-800f8158b4c8",
                    "name": "Slovenia",
                    "iso_alpha_2": "SI",
                    "iso_alpha_3": "SVN",
                    "native_name": "Slovenija",
                    "phone_code": 386,
                    "capital": "Ljubljana",
                    "continent": "Europe",
                    "languages": "{\"slv\":\"Slovene\"}",
                    "address_format": "{{recipient}}\n{{street}}\n{{postalcode}} {{city}}\n{{country}}",
                    "flag": "https://cdn.countryflags.com/thumbs/slovenia/flag-400.png",
                    "time_zone": "[\"Europe\\/Ljubljana\"]",
                    "locales": null,
                    "isActive": null,
                    "currency_id": "00cb7204-fb53-4cb7-8f59-ea3fe824c803",
                    "created_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:26.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:27.000000Z",
                    "deleted_at": null
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "0eaebeb9-1108-4ba8-afc1-1f4e72652631",
                "product_id": "087fd1dd-d4e2-4a1a-8f62-0481203e5afd",
                "country_id": "bea0c034-2e18-441b-b01c-08aeddb3018b",
                "name": "Finer Dicer Container 200ml",
                "description": "#",
                "created_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:28.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:28.000000Z",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "country": {
                    "id": "bea0c034-2e18-441b-b01c-08aeddb3018b",
                    "name": "Portugal",
                    "iso_alpha_2": "PT",
                    "iso_alpha_3": "PRT",
                    "native_name": "Portugal",
                    "phone_code": 351,
                    "capital": "Lisbon",
                    "continent": "Europe",
                    "languages": "{\"por\":\"Portuguese\"}",
                    "address_format": "{{recipient}}\n{{street}}\n{{postalcode}} {{city}} {{region_short}}\n{{country}}",
                    "flag": "https://cdn.countryflags.com/thumbs/portugal/flag-400.png",
                    "time_zone": "[\"Atlantic\\/Azores\",\"Atlantic\\/Madeira\",\"Europe\\/Lisbon\"]",
                    "locales": null,
                    "isActive": null,
                    "currency_id": "00cb7204-fb53-4cb7-8f59-ea3fe824c803",
                    "created_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:26.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:27.000000Z",
                    "deleted_at": null
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "13f53b73-bea0-4e89-be4b-fdca360bcaa9",
                "product_id": "087fd1dd-d4e2-4a1a-8f62-0481203e5afd",
                "country_id": "5accef6d-b4c9-4867-b369-77a5c472708e",
                "name": "Finer Dicer Container 200ml",
                "description": "#",
                "created_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:28.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:28.000000Z",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "country": {
                    "id": "5accef6d-b4c9-4867-b369-77a5c472708e",
                    "name": "Slovakia",
                    "iso_alpha_2": "SK",
                    "iso_alpha_3": "SVK",
                    "native_name": "Slovensko",
                    "phone_code": 421,
                    "capital": "Bratislava",
                    "continent": "Europe",
                    "languages": "{\"slk\":\"Slovak\"}",
                    "address_format": "{{recipient}}\n{{street}}\n{{postalcode}} {{city}}\n{{country}}",
                    "flag": "https://cdn.countryflags.com/thumbs/slovakia/flag-400.png",
                    "time_zone": "[\"Europe\\/Bratislava\"]",
                    "locales": null,
                    "isActive": null,
                    "currency_id": "00cb7204-fb53-4cb7-8f59-ea3fe824c803",
                    "created_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:26.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:26.000000Z",
                    "deleted_at": null
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "1d571e6a-8da0-42de-8cc9-460a297b2f63",
                "product_id": "087fd1dd-d4e2-4a1a-8f62-0481203e5afd",
                "country_id": "8d7c794c-468d-4759-abc9-04f6ad0137ed",
                "name": "Finer Dicer Container 200ml",
                "description": "#",
                "created_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:28.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:28.000000Z",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "country": {
                    "id": "8d7c794c-468d-4759-abc9-04f6ad0137ed",
                    "name": "Poland",
                    "iso_alpha_2": "PL",
                    "iso_alpha_3": "POL",
                    "native_name": "Polska",
                    "phone_code": 48,
                    "capital": "Warsaw",
                    "continent": "Europe",
                    "languages": "{\"pol\":\"Polish\"}",
                    "address_format": "{{recipient}}\n{{street}}\n{{postalcode}} {{city}}\n{{region}}\n{{country}}",
                    "flag": "https://cdn.countryflags.com/thumbs/poland/flag-400.png",
                    "time_zone": "[\"Europe\\/Warsaw\"]",
                    "locales": null,
                    "isActive": null,
                    "currency_id": "27cc3885-756c-4f84-a6ac-69421a9e3bdb",
                    "created_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:26.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:27.000000Z",
                    "deleted_at": null
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "2ed66c79-ff2e-4999-baf1-4c73d1bf7d94",
                "product_id": "087fd1dd-d4e2-4a1a-8f62-0481203e5afd",
                "country_id": "e5e60f31-d3f8-4d7e-a79c-1c2cb69343a1",
                "name": "Finer Dicer Container 200ml",
                "description": "#",
                "created_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:28.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:28.000000Z",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "country": {
                    "id": "e5e60f31-d3f8-4d7e-a79c-1c2cb69343a1",
                    "name": "Spain",
                    "iso_alpha_2": "ES",
                    "iso_alpha_3": "ESP",
                    "native_name": "Espanya",
                    "phone_code": 34,
                    "capital": "Madrid",
                    "continent": "Europe",
                    "languages": "{\"cat\":\"Catalan\",\"eus\":\"Basque\",\"glg\":\"Galician\",\"oci\":\"Occitan\",\"spa\":\"Spanish\"}",
                    "address_format": "{{recipient}}\n{{street}}\n{{postalcode}} {{city}}\n{{region}}\n{{country}}",
                    "flag": "https://cdn.countryflags.com/thumbs/spain/flag-400.png",
                    "time_zone": "[\"Africa\\/Ceuta\",\"Atlantic\\/Canary\",\"Europe\\/Madrid\"]",
                    "locales": null,
                    "isActive": null,
                    "currency_id": "00cb7204-fb53-4cb7-8f59-ea3fe824c803",
                    "created_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:26.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:27.000000Z",
                    "deleted_at": null
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "3432938c-07fe-4405-a8c6-2e6989639e9b",
                "product_id": "087fd1dd-d4e2-4a1a-8f62-0481203e5afd",
                "country_id": "20b59d05-e320-4b4c-baf6-d4eede957858",
                "name": "Finer Dicer Container 200ml",
                "description": "#",
                "created_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:28.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:28.000000Z",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "country": {
                    "id": "20b59d05-e320-4b4c-baf6-d4eede957858",
                    "name": "Romania",
                    "iso_alpha_2": "RO",
                    "iso_alpha_3": "ROU",
                    "native_name": "România",
                    "phone_code": 40,
                    "capital": "Bucharest",
                    "continent": "Europe",
                    "languages": "{\"ron\":\"Romanian\"}",
                    "address_format": "{{recipient}}\n{{street}}\n{{postalcode}} {{city}}\n{{country}}",
                    "flag": "https://cdn.countryflags.com/thumbs/romania/flag-400.png",
                    "time_zone": "[\"Europe\\/Bucharest\"]",
                    "locales": null,
                    "isActive": null,
                    "currency_id": "03ff705a-a0a4-49bb-879b-da3ee7f4f396",
                    "created_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:26.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:26.000000Z",
                    "deleted_at": null
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "38fd49fb-6aa5-4965-b70a-81fce329d2a1",
                "product_id": "087fd1dd-d4e2-4a1a-8f62-0481203e5afd",
                "country_id": "0ae18d7b-3d51-46d4-a577-e3802127d3f0",
                "name": "Finer Dicer Container 200ml",
                "description": "#",
                "created_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:28.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:28.000000Z",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "country": {
                    "id": "0ae18d7b-3d51-46d4-a577-e3802127d3f0",
                    "name": "Hungary",
                    "iso_alpha_2": "HU",
                    "iso_alpha_3": "HUN",
                    "native_name": "Magyarország",
                    "phone_code": 36,
                    "capital": "Budapest",
                    "continent": "Europe",
                    "languages": "{\"hun\":\"Hungarian\"}",
                    "address_format": "{{recipient}}\n{{city}}\n{{street}}\n{{postalcode}}\n{{country}}",
                    "flag": "https://cdn.countryflags.com/thumbs/hungary/flag-400.png",
                    "time_zone": "[\"Europe\\/Budapest\"]",
                    "locales": null,
                    "isActive": null,
                    "currency_id": "d6481be9-be00-4cd9-a159-62e7330de03a",
                    "created_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:26.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:26.000000Z",
                    "deleted_at": null
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "3c07fe0f-4989-4023-add7-ae20f83580c6",
                "product_id": "087fd1dd-d4e2-4a1a-8f62-0481203e5afd",
                "country_id": "a5b579d8-044c-48d0-8134-2aef3e8ee5c9",
                "name": "Finer Dicer Container 200ml",
                "description": "#",
                "created_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:28.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:28.000000Z",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "country": {
                    "id": "a5b579d8-044c-48d0-8134-2aef3e8ee5c9",
                    "name": "Lithuania",
                    "iso_alpha_2": "LT",
                    "iso_alpha_3": "LTU",
                    "native_name": "Lietuva",
                    "phone_code": 370,
                    "capital": "Vilnius",
                    "continent": "Europe",
                    "languages": "{\"lit\":\"Lithuanian\"}",
                    "address_format": "{{recipient}} {{street}} {{postalcode}} {{city}} {{region}} {{country}}",
                    "flag": "https://cdn.countryflags.com/thumbs/lithuania/flag-400.png",
                    "time_zone": "[\"Europe\\/Vilnius\"]",
                    "locales": null,
                    "isActive": null,
                    "currency_id": "00cb7204-fb53-4cb7-8f59-ea3fe824c803",
                    "created_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:26.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:27.000000Z",
                    "deleted_at": null
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "3de71c3e-789b-47e5-8b09-1cfa1fd6a776",
                "product_id": "087fd1dd-d4e2-4a1a-8f62-0481203e5afd",
                "country_id": "85a30728-8358-4389-b580-d8e52798e870",
                "name": "Finer Dicer Container 200ml",
                "description": "#",
                "created_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:28.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:28.000000Z",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "country": {
                    "id": "85a30728-8358-4389-b580-d8e52798e870",
                    "name": "Bulgaria",
                    "iso_alpha_2": "BG",
                    "iso_alpha_3": "BGR",
                    "native_name": "България",
                    "phone_code": 359,
                    "capital": "Sofia",
                    "continent": "Europe",
                    "languages": "{\"bul\":\"Bulgarian\"}",
                    "address_format": "{{recipient}}\n{{street}}\n{{postalcode}} {{city}}\n{{country}}",
                    "flag": "https://cdn.countryflags.com/thumbs/bulgaria/flag-400.png",
                    "time_zone": "[\"Europe\\/Sofia\"]",
                    "locales": null,
                    "isActive": null,
                    "currency_id": "277d07c8-bf67-4e74-a34e-2f33933cb448",
                    "created_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:26.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:27.000000Z",
                    "deleted_at": null
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "442d8f81-f77e-4f05-af2b-28c7bd5a9bdf",
                "product_id": "087fd1dd-d4e2-4a1a-8f62-0481203e5afd",
                "country_id": "dd1e92ec-911b-4db0-9922-e9955b6f12f4",
                "name": "Finer Dicer Container 200ml",
                "description": "#",
                "created_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:28.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:28.000000Z",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "country": {
                    "id": "dd1e92ec-911b-4db0-9922-e9955b6f12f4",
                    "name": "Estonia",
                    "iso_alpha_2": "EE",
                    "iso_alpha_3": "EST",
                    "native_name": "Eesti",
                    "phone_code": 372,
                    "capital": "Tallinn",
                    "continent": "Europe",
                    "languages": "{\"est\":\"Estonian\"}",
                    "address_format": "{{recipient}} {{street}} {{postalcode}} {{city}} {{region}} {{country}}",
                    "flag": "https://cdn.countryflags.com/thumbs/estonia/flag-400.png",
                    "time_zone": "[\"Europe\\/Tallinn\"]",
                    "locales": null,
                    "isActive": null,
                    "currency_id": "00cb7204-fb53-4cb7-8f59-ea3fe824c803",
                    "created_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:26.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:27.000000Z",
                    "deleted_at": null
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "5999dd11-2786-48c4-bf82-4d378c3421c7",
                "product_id": "087fd1dd-d4e2-4a1a-8f62-0481203e5afd",
                "country_id": "231037e7-f30e-47d8-9615-ddb81b9e2cb9",
                "name": "Finer Dicer Container 200ml",
                "description": "#",
                "created_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:28.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:28.000000Z",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "country": {
                    "id": "231037e7-f30e-47d8-9615-ddb81b9e2cb9",
                    "name": "Croatia",
                    "iso_alpha_2": "HR",
                    "iso_alpha_3": "HRV",
                    "native_name": "Hrvatska",
                    "phone_code": 385,
                    "capital": "Zagreb",
                    "continent": "Europe",
                    "languages": "{\"hrv\":\"Croatian\"}",
                    "address_format": "{{recipient}}\n{{street}}\n{{postalcode}} {{city}}\n{{country}}",
                    "flag": "https://cdn.countryflags.com/thumbs/croatia/flag-400.png",
                    "time_zone": "[\"Europe\\/Zagreb\"]",
                    "locales": null,
                    "isActive": null,
                    "currency_id": "553dc2ad-b772-4dbf-9432-107d5733099a",
                    "created_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:26.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:26.000000Z",
                    "deleted_at": null
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "65c9c254-0ae8-454c-9cd4-e9803fe80395",
                "product_id": "087fd1dd-d4e2-4a1a-8f62-0481203e5afd",
                "country_id": "e6c6030b-fdd6-4d52-ab8f-8f4618acf62b",
                "name": "Finer Dicer Container 200ml",
                "description": "#",
                "created_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:28.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:28.000000Z",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "country": {
                    "id": "e6c6030b-fdd6-4d52-ab8f-8f4618acf62b",
                    "name": "Germany",
                    "iso_alpha_2": "DE",
                    "iso_alpha_3": "DEU",
                    "native_name": "Deutschland",
                    "phone_code": 49,
                    "capital": "Berlin",
                    "continent": "Europe",
                    "languages": "{\"deu\":\"German\"}",
                    "address_format": "{{recipient}}\n{{street}}\n{{postalcode}} {{city}}\n{{country}}",
                    "flag": "https://cdn.countryflags.com/thumbs/germany/flag-400.png",
                    "time_zone": "[\"Europe\\/Berlin\",\"Europe\\/Busingen\"]",
                    "locales": null,
                    "isActive": null,
                    "currency_id": "00cb7204-fb53-4cb7-8f59-ea3fe824c803",
                    "created_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:26.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:27.000000Z",
                    "deleted_at": null
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "94abdee5-5853-41d1-b8f8-8044308483cf",
                "product_id": "087fd1dd-d4e2-4a1a-8f62-0481203e5afd",
                "country_id": "7156e359-f00b-4da5-9083-58e9b0b401ce",
                "name": "Finer Dicer Container 200ml",
                "description": "#",
                "created_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:28.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:28.000000Z",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "country": {
                    "id": "7156e359-f00b-4da5-9083-58e9b0b401ce",
                    "name": "Czech Republic",
                    "iso_alpha_2": "CZ",
                    "iso_alpha_3": "CZE",
                    "native_name": "Česká republika",
                    "phone_code": 420,
                    "capital": "Prague",
                    "continent": "Europe",
                    "languages": "{\"ces\":\"Czech\",\"slk\":\"Slovak\"}",
                    "address_format": "{{recipient}}\n{{street}}\n{{postalcode}} {{city}}\n{{country}}",
                    "flag": "https://cdn.countryflags.com/thumbs/czech-republic/flag-400.png",
                    "time_zone": "[\"Europe\\/Prague\"]",
                    "locales": null,
                    "isActive": null,
                    "currency_id": "4c463089-f1a8-4efb-a063-100877c2f8ef",
                    "created_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:26.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:27.000000Z",
                    "deleted_at": null
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "be6242a3-7b83-47d4-91d4-284ab2183ee9",
                "product_id": "087fd1dd-d4e2-4a1a-8f62-0481203e5afd",
                "country_id": "11e0a165-1148-45db-82df-0fd9f012e0d3",
                "name": "Finer Dicer Container 200ml",
                "description": "#",
                "created_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:28.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:28.000000Z",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "country": {
                    "id": "11e0a165-1148-45db-82df-0fd9f012e0d3",
                    "name": "Latvia",
                    "iso_alpha_2": "LV",
                    "iso_alpha_3": "LVA",
                    "native_name": "Latvija",
                    "phone_code": 371,
                    "capital": "Riga",
                    "continent": "Europe",
                    "languages": "{\"lav\":\"Latvian\"}",
                    "address_format": "{{recipient}} {{street}} {{postalcode}} {{city}} {{region}} {{country}}",
                    "flag": "https://cdn.countryflags.com/thumbs/latvia/flag-400.png",
                    "time_zone": "[\"Europe\\/Riga\"]",
                    "locales": null,
                    "isActive": null,
                    "currency_id": "00cb7204-fb53-4cb7-8f59-ea3fe824c803",
                    "created_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:26.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:26.000000Z",
                    "deleted_at": null
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "ee1fe9ee-9331-4459-82a5-4ce54a713c2f",
                "product_id": "087fd1dd-d4e2-4a1a-8f62-0481203e5afd",
                "country_id": "39399fb1-0400-487a-ae36-a9a98bf5780f",
                "name": "Finer Dicer Container 200ml",
                "description": "#",
                "created_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:28.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:28.000000Z",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "country": {
                    "id": "39399fb1-0400-487a-ae36-a9a98bf5780f",
                    "name": "Greece",
                    "iso_alpha_2": "GR",
                    "iso_alpha_3": "GRC",
                    "native_name": "Ελλάδα",
                    "phone_code": 30,
                    "capital": "Athens",
                    "continent": "Europe",
                    "languages": "{\"ell\":\"Greek\"}",
                    "address_format": "{{recipient}}\n{{street}}\n{{postalcode}} {{city}}\n{{country}}",
                    "flag": "https://cdn.countryflags.com/thumbs/greece/flag-400.png",
                    "time_zone": "[\"Europe\\/Athens\"]",
                    "locales": null,
                    "isActive": null,
                    "currency_id": "00cb7204-fb53-4cb7-8f59-ea3fe824c803",
                    "created_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:26.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:26.000000Z",
                    "deleted_at": null
                }
            }
        ],
        "images": [
            {
                "id": "a59b174e-5d73-4055-825b-99d7ee814fa9",
                "product_id": "087fd1dd-d4e2-4a1a-8f62-0481203e5afd",
                "order": null,
                "name": "container200_feature_image",
                "image_url": "https://globaxy.com/api/gmanager/accessories/nicer-dicer-200ml-box.jpg",
                "image_path": null,
                "created_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:32.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-04-21T08:19:32.000000Z",
                "deleted_at": null
            }
        ],
        "packages": []
    }
}
```

So I have created resource that looks like:

```
public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'sku' => $this->sku,
            'type' => $this->type,
            'info' => InfoCollection::collection($this->info)
        ];

        //return parent::toArray($request);
    }
```

So now, the problem is with InfoCollection, I want to pass this info and show them, but every time when I try to get id, for example, it says that

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::$id

But it's foreaching values for sure, because I tried like:

```
class InfoCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
    
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return ([
            'id' => 'hereis id',
        ]);
    }
}
```

And it's foreaching, but I can't get any value.

Any ideas how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to get the ID. Are you not supposed to do this: `$this->info->id`